# pandas create quantiles for a column based weighted by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'v': [100, 300, 200, 900, 100, 400, 300, 300, 800, 1100], 's':[1.1, 2.7, 0.87, 1.6, 3.2, 0.2, 1.1, 0.3, 1.2, 1.3]})


    s       v
0   1.10    100
1   2.70    300
2   0.87    200
3   1.60    900
4   3.20    100
5   0.20    400
6   1.10    300
7   0.30    300
8   1.20    800
9   1.30    1100
```

I want to get the quantiles almost similar to

```
pd.qcut(df["s"], 3,labels=[-1, 0, 1])
```

but instead of having each bin contain an equal number of entries, I would like to create bins such that the sum of v for each category is equal.

Something like

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'v': [100, 300, 200, 900, 100, 400, 300, 300, 800, 1100], 's':[1.1, 2.7, 0.87, 1.6, 3.2, 0.2, 1.1, 0.3, 1.2, 1.3] ,\
              'c': [-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0]})


   c    s   v
0   -1  1.10    100
1   1   2.70    300
2   -1  0.87    200
3   1   1.60    900
4   1   3.20    100
5   -1  0.20    400
6   -1  1.10    300
7   -1  0.30    300
8   0   1.20    800
9   0   1.30    1100
```

Interpolation doesn't matter much as the actual set is quite large.
I can achieve this by sorting for s, doing a `cumsum` on v and then setting values based on comparing the `cumsum` to the total sum. But I am wondering if there is any approach using some pandas magic

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quite awful if you have a large dataframe, but here something different and simpler from your solution (which is nice):

```
pd.qcut(np.concatenate([[s]*v for s,v in zip(df.s, df.v)]), 3, labels=[-1,0,1])
```

You may check before with `cumsum` on `v` if your computer is going to explode before...

Comment: Thanks, interesting solution. But yea, that numpy will blow up with the actual data